# Is this headlice or bed bug

Tags: species-identification

[image]
This is very small. About the size of a grain of rice. I Felt it crawling in my hair.  When I brushed my hair off this fell out in the sink. I was wondering if it's lice. I'm in Mojave county Az

Comment: Please add your location and the approximate size of the specimen. Both are needed for an accurate ID. I also advise that you upload any additional pictures you may have of the specimen. Currently, your post is lacking adequate detail and will be closed and unanswered. Please [edit] accordingly. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Thrips, order Thysanoptera. Not harmful. Not a bedbug or a louse. You can read about them here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips 
(by the way the singular form of "Thrips" is "Thrips": there is no such thing as a "Thrip")